# ALIAS record pointing to AWS endpoint, bad idea?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-rds

We have an AWS RDS Multi AZ deployment and one of our teams is using a subdomain (rds1.company.com) to access it. The subdomain uses an ALIAS record to point to the AWS endpoint and when I replaced the instance with a restored snapshot last week, it took at least an hour to refresh and point to the new instance.

Since the idea of a Multi AZ deployment is so that the endpoint can point to the fallback server whenever needed, isn't a custom domain a bad idea? I was told by our network admin that the ALIAS record refreshes once an hour.

Answer (score 2):

Route53 ALIAS records have a fixed TTL of 60 seconds. This is stated in the Route53 FAQ. Public Internet DNS servers often times ignore the TTL.

Route53 ALIAS records do not support RDS, so you are most likely using a CNAME with a TTL of 3600 seconds. The TTL (expiration) can be set as short as 1 second but Amazon recommends a minimum TTL of 10 seconds.

Multi-AZ RDS endpoint will failover automatically in less than 60 seconds with Aurora and as fast as 30 seconds with MariaDB Connector/J. Other instance types can take from one to two minutes. This is covered in the RDS FAQ.

Make sure that the Route53 CNAME record is using the RDS DNS Name (endpoint) and not the IP address. You can set the CNAME TTL to be a small as you need.

[Amazon Route 53 FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/)

[Amazon RDS FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/)

Comment: We're not using Route 53 for DNS. We're using DNSimple. I have checked the folks who run it and it's definitely an ALIAS record.

Comment: TXT record says TTL 3599, so I guess it's best we use the endpoint instead.

Comment: The default TTL for DNSimple is 3600 seconds and is changeable. This is probably the reason for the 1 hour delay. I am not sure after reading the documentation that I would use DNSimple ALIAS records for RDS. I would use their CNAME record so that the RDS DNS name is resolved by the AWS DNS server instead of DNSimple caching the RDS A records.

Comment: I don't control that domain's records. I'm not sure why it's not CNAME either. Nevertheless, it's a DB server so we can simply switch to using the endpoint URL directly.